# I have configutred phpmyadmin on ubuntu but it showing raw file instead phpmyadmin login page

Tags: phpmyadmin

[image: Here is screen shot of my phpmyadmin error page]

Please tell me

How to handle this error

Comment: Which webserver are you using? The problem is that the webserver isn't properly interpreting PHP scripts, which might mean your PHP installation is incomplete or just misconfigured.

Comment: Apache web server

Comment: Presumably you're using the package manager to handle installing Apache and PHP, so the very detailed and informative answer at http://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server should help.